# Browsers double-closing my tags? Invalid markup?

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation

In my html template, based on Zurb Foundation , I have following code:

```html
<div id="top-bar">
  <div id="top-bar-top-cont"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <p id="toplogo">
        <h3>some text</h3>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I check the code source, firefox warns me there is an issue with closing p tag, with red color.

In firebug source, I see it self closing p tag and div tags around it.
So, it doesnt display things properly.

Even when I pasted this snippet here, the editor showed red closing tags for p & outermost div.

Do I have error in this html?

Am I missing something?

This is my whole document:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css" />
    <script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="top-bar">
  <div id="top-bar-top-cont"></div>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="large-12 columns">
         <p id="toplogo">
    <h3>some text</h3>
   </p>
       </div>
     </div> 
   </div>

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because Firefox does not expect any heading tag like `<h3>` inside `<p>` tag. Therefore, when Firefox encounters the `<h3>` tag in your example, it automatically closes the `<p>` tag. You must put the `<h3>` tag outside `<p>` tag.

Comment: Yup, it seems to be something along those lines, 
I changed p to div and it works.

Ill wait for more explanations till I accept your answer.

Comment: It is not just Firefox; all browsers new enough to implement the HTML5 parser algorithm will do the same.